In terms of game design, what's the role of the dice in 30 Seconds?
In the game "30 seconds" before a team's turn, they roll a handicap dice that subtracts either 0, 1 or 2 from their number of guessed answers. What does this mechanic bring to the game? What game design problem does it solve?

It's not solving any problem, unless having the outcome determined by the players is seen as a problem. It just makes the game more random / less determined by player actions.


At the start of each round, the team throws a special 30 Seconds die
to determine a handicap. The die has six sides with values of 0, 1 or
2. This handicap will be subtracted from the number of correct guesses during that turn to determine how many squares their token may
advance, therefore 0 is preferable. Source

Therefore a higher number makes sure you need to have at least a certain minimum of correct answers per round to be able to advance. If both teams are equally strong, it adds a slight variance/ random element into it who is winning - if everyone answers everything correctly, the team with the lowest numbers thrown on the dice wins.
